# Is anybody aware of an application that does what FreeMyPDF.com does (frees 'secured' PDFs)

Tags: encryption

The site works smooth, but I have so many PDFs I want to break that batch processing would be truly ideal. I already tried Free PDF Unlocker and it didn't work.

Comment: A quick Google reveals multiple programs

Comment: @ekaj imho, when I ask a question, I always appreciate answers based on experience. I recall when I was googling for it, there were hundreds of choices. I don't even remember why I chose the one I did, I'm just glad I was happy with it -- and happy enough to see this question and try to help.

Comment: Thank you, Chris K. I've determined that I need a program that can _remove_ the owner password. The tool you recommended can only recover it.

Answer (score 1):

I [bought this](http://www.lostpassword.com/acrobat.htm) for my business. It has worked all but once. Rather than tell you the password, it saves an unlocked version of the file. It's been a while since I used it, but with the standard windows GUI, I want to think it can do more than one at a time. There's a free demo...